# How to add a hyperlink to a outputted value to link it its source

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following formula which outputs a value from another sheet. This is functioning just as it should.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Planner!$B$11:$B$164,SMALL(IF(($F$4=Planner!$A$11:$A$330),ROW(Planner!$A$11:$A$308)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$11:$B$373))+1,""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")`

The formula and functions above are new to me, so I am not entirely sure how to add a link.

The formula above is looping through the data I have to check if the row has `$F$4` in it, so adding the hyperlink is a bit more complex.

How can I add a hyperlink to the output, so that it will hyperlink to where the source cell?

Main sheet

[image]

Planner Sheet

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, and getting to the answer requires understanding a few principals:

1. The formula you implemented is known as "n-th lookup". Normal Excel VLOOKUP will return only the first match, but with "n-th lookup" you create a list of all matching entries (with each list entry containing its row index number if it matches, or "" if it doesn't), then use the SMALL function to return the n'th smallest matching row index number. n in this case is derived from the current row number the formula is in, so that as you copy and paste the "n-th lookup" formula downwards, you are successively returning the next matching row index. Finally the formula uses INDEX to look up the associated value from column B at that index.
2. INDEX returns the value as a reference, meaning it can also be used as an argument in other functions that require a references such as CELL
3. HYPERLINK can generate a link to a cell in the current open Excel file, but requires a text reference to the cell and not just a normal reference. This is because HYPERLINK is primarily intended to link to websites or documents via a text URL. Luckily we can use the CELL function to return a text URL or address to any reference in the current workbook, e.g. `=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",Sheet1!A1),"Go to cell A1")`

We now have all the ingredients to mix together a working formula:

```
=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",__INDEX PART OF YOUR FORMULA__),__YOUR WHOLE FORMULA__)
```

So

```
=HYPERLINK(CELL("address", INDEX(Planner!$B$11:$B$373,SMALL(IF(($F$4=Planner!$A$11:$A$373),ROW(Planner!$A$11:$A$373)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$11:$B$373))+1,""),ROWS($A$1:A1)))), IFERROR(INDEX(Planner!$B$11:$B$373,SMALL(IF(($F$4=Planner!$A$11:$A$373),ROW(Planner!$A$11:$A$373)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$11:$B$373))+1,""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")
```

We have to remove the IFERROR part, as IFERROR forces the reference returned by INDEX to resolve to its value, meaning CELL would not be able to resolve it. Unfortunately as a consequence hyperlink will return a #NUM! error when their is no longer any matching rows to return. To fix this, we simply have to replace the "" returned by the ELSE part of the IF with a the last index number in the list i.e. 373-11+1

```
=HYPERLINK(CELL("address", INDEX(Planner!$B$11:$B$373,SMALL(IF(($F$4=Planner!$A$11:$A$373),ROW(Planner!$A$11:$A$373)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$11:$B$373))+1,373-11+1),ROWS($A$1:A1)))), IFERROR(INDEX(Planner!$B$11:$B$373,SMALL(IF(($F$4=Planner!$A$11:$A$373),ROW(Planner!$A$11:$A$373)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$11:$B$373))+1,""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),"")
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! Much appreciated. After trying this, the cell turns into a hyperlink, but when clicked on, a 404 error appears in an alert prompt.

Comment: It might be a version issue or some other typo. Perhaps read the in-app help for HYPERLINK in your version of excel. Also try basic hyperlinks first i.e. `=HYPERLINK(CELL("address", sheet1!A1),  "goto A1")`

Comment: Ps. Make sure to save your file first. Unsaved files might also cause problems

Comment: I have this `=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDEX(Planner!$B$13:$B$375,SMALL(IF(($F$4=Planner!$A$13:$A$375),ROW(Planner!$A$13:$A$375)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$13:$B$375))+1,373-11+1),ROWS($A$1:A1)))),IFERROR(INDEX(Planner!$B$13:$B$375,SMALL(IF(($F$4=Planner!$A$13:$A$375),ROW(Planner!$A$13:$A$375)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$13:$B$375))+1,""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),""))`

Comment: I see error 404 is a file error, like for some reason hyperlink cannot locate your file via the path provided (from CELL) - which is why I thought maybe your file wasn't saved. If you just use `=CELL("address", A1)` what do you get? Does it give the correct filename?

Comment: Ps. The formula in your comment above works for me on Excel 365. Incidentally my computer crashed earlier (unrelated), and Excel recovered the test file. The hyperlinks in the recovered test file threw file errors when clicked on, until I saved the recovered workbook in a normal folder. Make sure your file is stored somewhere simple and accessible. It may be a file/folder rights issue.

Comment: Yes, I get $A$1 when I do `=CELL("address", A1)`

Comment: This is exactly what shows up in the prompt. `Unable to open https://sharepoint.com/perssonal/me/Documents/Documents/%bLaunch%20Playbook.xslm%5dPlanner`!$B$13. The internet site reports that the item you requested could not be found. (HTTP/1.0 404)`

Comment: What do you get if you reference a cell in another sheet? e.g. `=CELL("address", Sheet2!A1)`? If would seem accessing the file stored on sharepoint is the problem (probably because Excel's built-in browser isn't considered signed-in into sharepoint). First try saving on your local hard disk and test. Then try a workaround with sharepoint (e.g. use onedrive client to sync a local folder with the sharepoint folder instead and edit from the local folder, or perhaps try logging into sharepoint first using either/both the Edge and old Internet Explorer browsers.

Comment: I do not get the correct info. I just tried it and get `[Launch (the tilde shows up)

Comment: The launch thing will happen if you dont have a sheet2. Make sure you have a sheet named sheet2 or used a name of another sheet. Have you tried saving it on your local drive?

Comment: When I reference it correctly, it still shows '[Launch ... The name of the file is "Launch Playbook". I'm not sure if it is taking the first word from that.

Comment: I think I may have stumbled onto the solution. CELL adds extra single quotes `'` to the filename string if it contains spaces or special characters. Excel itself doesn't mind these quotes if you use it with say INDIRECT but unfortunately HYPERLINK does. You can remove these with `=SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address", Planner!A1), "'", "")`. Painfully, if your sheet name does contain spaces, you must have the sheet name in single quotes but not the filename for HYPERLINK to work. Easy way out, just don't use spaces in sheet names and filenames.

Comment: PS. If you find a filename reference like this `[Launch~1.xls]Planner!A1` this too should be fine. In some cases, especially with long filenames, Excel will use the old DOS 8dot3 filename standard (depending on your version of windows and/or office).  If you are familiar with command prompt commands, you can navigate to your folder with "cd ..." and then "dir /x" to see shortnames for all files.

Comment: Its worth noting that like Jeorje's solution e.g. `HYPERLINK("#Planner!A1", "Go to A1")` should work, though I am not sure in which version of Office the "#"  method of self-referencing got support. Excel's own help file still recommends using the CELL method to HYPERLINK to cells internal to the workbook - without mentioning the filename-with-spaces-bug of course. Finally, I'm still not sure why you got the error when linking to the "https://sharepoint.com..." file - whether that's because of the cloud access rights, the filename-with-spaces, or a bit of both (URL's use e.g. %20 for a space).

Comment: Thank you. I will try out the `SUBSTITUTE` method. Do I get rid of the `HYPERLINK` function altogether or wrap `SUBSTITUTE` around the `CELL` while keeping `HYPERLINK` as the parent?

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion. When I opened this up in the browser, it worked. Not sure why it didn't through the Excel app. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following, using exactly the formula segments you currently use.

It will display the lookup result, but the hyperlink will go to the located value's actual cell.

```
HYPERLINK("#Planner!B"  &  TargetRow,  Target)
```

For `Target`, substitute your entire current formula. This is the part that will show the located value in your output cell/s.

For `TargetRow` you only need a portion of the current formula, that portion that generates the row which `INDEX` returns.

Since you know the sheet, you just enter it as text, and that would feel logical. But you also know the column you desire in the row found:  column B. While it might not feel logical to simply enter that as text when contemplating how to do the hyperlink, once it occurs to you, it's natural to do so.

So put together, it looks like so:  (until you can move users forward and use `LET`)

```
= HYPERLINK("#Planner!B"  &  SMALL(IF($F$4=Planner!$A$11:$A$330,ROW(Planner!$A$11:$A$308)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$11:$B$373))+1,""),ROWS(Sheet1!$A$1:A1))+10,  IFERROR(INDEX(Planner!$B$11:$B$164, 
SMALL(IF(($F$4=Planner!$A$11:$A$330),ROW(Planner!$A$11:$A$308)-MIN(ROW(Planner!$B$11:$B$373))+1,""),ROWS($A$1:A1))),""))
```

A potential formatting quirk comes to mind. My version is 2205 and when I click anywhere in the cell, it activates the hyperlink effect. In every version I've had prior to this (allowing for not making a new `HYPERLINK` formula for perhaps six months), the full cell clicking ability only happened if I chose a non-standard horizontal alignment option when formatting the cell. Otherwise, it only happened if I clicked directly on the displayed contents and NOT in whitespace. Something to consider if your users report "um, the hyperlink doesn't work" and that applies to any hyperlink, not just these. Conversely, if you experience the "clickable whitespace selects the cell, not the hyperlink" effect, that too can be of use in other applications.

(Interestingly, when I use `LET` (not available in Excel-2010 which you have tagged the question with), the formula result does not get formatted as a hyperlink. So if you eventually can use that function to make the formula look simple, you would have to manually format the formula's cells to look like a hyperlink (underlined, blue color) though a clicked cell's hyperlink would not change to the purple color showing it had been used at least once.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. I tried this out. What it is doing is opening up a file window (a type of window that appears when you save are saving a document). I accidentally clicked on Excel 2010. My version is 2016.